# Turning a list of abs pathed files to a comma delimited string of files in bash

Tags: bash

I have been working in bash, and need to create a string argument.  bash is a newish for me, to the point that I dont know how to build a string in bash from a list.

// foo.txt is a list of abs file names.

```
/foo/bar/a.txt
/foo/bar/b.txt
/delta/test/b.txt
```

should turn into: `a.txt,b.txt,b.txt`

OR: `/foo/bar/a.txt,/foo/bar/b.txt,/delta/test/b.txt`

code

```
s = ""
for file in $(cat foo.txt);
do
    #what goes here?    s += $file  ?
done

myShellScript --script $s
```

I figure there was an easy way to do this.

Comment: ```cat foo.txt | tr $'\n' ,```

Comment: Actually there's an even easier way involving `sed`, but... that'll do.

Comment: If you are not *concatenating* 2 files, then `cat ..whatever..` is a **UUOc**  (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*). Better `while read file; do #suff; done <foo.txt`

Comment: Use `awk -v FS=/ '{print $NF}' foo.txt | paste -sd ","` for last field alone and `paste -sd "," foo.txt` for the whole line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with for loop:

```
for file in $(cat foo.txt);do echo -n "$file",;done|sed 's/,$/\n/g'
```

with tr:

```
cat foo.txt|tr '\n' ','|sed 's/,$/\n/g'
```

only sed:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="foo.txt"
while IFS= read -r var
  do
  basename $var >> tmp
  done < "$input"
paste -d, -s tmp > result.txt
```

output: `a.txt,b.txt,b.txt`

basename gets you the file names you need and paste will put them in the order you seem to need.

Answer (score 0):

The input field separator can be used with `set` to create split/join functionality:

```
# split the lines of foo.txt into positional parameters
IFS=$'\n'
set $(< foo.txt)

# join with commas
IFS=,
echo "$*"
```

For just the file names, add some sed:

```
IFS=$'\n'; set $(sed 's|.*/||' foo.txt); IFS=,; echo "$*"
```